# ./count:78: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby

I modified my post and managed to copy/paste the code here. I know it's ugly but really hope it's going to help to find the error. 
Error message is: "./v_c:2:in ': undefined local variable or method  ' for main:Object (NameError)"

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 
#
# This program is used for collecting web server visit information.
#
# Author: A. Genius
#
 
require 'optparse'
 
def print_usage
    puts "USAGE: v_c -d DNS_NAME"
    exit
end


 
# add option switch and handler
 
options = {}
 
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
   
# DNS_NAME argument
 options[:dns_name] = nil
    opts.on('-d', '--dns-name DNS_NAME', 'Specify a DNS NAME') { |dns_name| options[:dns_name] = dns_name }
   
# HELP argument
    options[:help] = nil
    opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Display usage') { |help| options[:help] = help }
end
 
option_parser.parse!
 
# verify arguments
 
if options[:dns_name] then
    dns_name = options[:dns_name]
else
  puts "Please set a balancer's DNS."
  print_usage
  exit
end
 
if options[:help] then
    print_usage
    exit
end
 
# Keep STDOUT
# orig_stdout = $stdout
 
# redirect stdout to /dev/null
# $stdout = File.new('/dev/null', 'w')
 
    server1_visit_count = 0
    server2_visit_count = 0
    server3_visit_count = 0
    server4_visit_count = 0
 
# starting to visit load balancing server
 
puts "Starting to visit load balancing server"

2000.times do

# visit load balancer
# o = "curl #{dns_name}"

o = "curl -s #{dns_name}"
if o =~ /server\s*1/i
    server1_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*2/i
    server2_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*3/i
    server3_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*4/i
    server4_visit_count += 1
end

    print "."
end

puts
puts '-------------------------'
puts ' Summary'
puts '-------------------------'
puts "Server1 visit counts : " + server1_visit_count.to_s
puts "Server2 visit counts : " + server2_visit_count.to_s
puts "Server3 visit counts : " + server3_visit_count.to_s
puts "Server4 visit counts : " + server4_visit_count.to_s
puts "total is: " +  (server1_visit_count + server2_visit_count + 

server3_visit_count + server4_visit_count).to_s
```

Comment: `elsif` is a single keyword, without spaces inside. Also, post the code, not screenshots, please.

Comment: What error you get on this line `puts "Total visit counts : "   + (server1_visit_count + server2_visit_count +      
server3_visit_count + server4_visit_count).to_s`?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the code into the question? I would be much easier to help you if I were able to paste the code into my favorite editor and maybe run it.

Comment: @J.D I just deleted the space between the first "+" sign, the one comes before "(server1_visit .."

Comment: @user2066392 accept the answer, since it is solved. Do not waste others time for something that is finnished..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh... String interpolation, once again... Replace this line 
`#o = 'curl #{dns_name}'` with:

```
#o = "curl #{dns_name}"
```

I explained why it was the problem below.

1. You can see from editor that `end` is not recognised. Maybe you copy/pasted some code before and some characters (like quotation marks) are not the same format as your editor uses. So rewriting this short peace of code might save your ###. And paste whats rewritten here :)
2. `elsif` writes as a single word, but Ruby probably understands it, since no error I got using it this way..
3. String interpolation is used with double quotes

`'curl -s #{dns}'`

Supposed to be:

`"curl -s #{dns}"`

(Expect you really want to output this as "`curl -s #{dns}`")

Was the problem one of these?

---

I just pasted this into repl.it and it works well. Please check if it meets your code (I have added a value to `dns_name` variable since I do not have it defined in my case):

```
dns_name = 10 
10.times do

# visit load balancer
#o = "curl #{dns_name}"

o = "curl -s #{dns_name}"
if o =~ /server\s*1/i
  server1_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*2/i
  server2_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*3/i
  server3_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*4/i
  server4_visit_count += 1
end

print "."
end
```

---

Try to copy/paste this and tell if any errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 
#
# This program is used for collecting web server visit information.
#
# Author: A. Genius
#
 
require 'optparse'
 
def print_usage
    puts "USAGE: v_c -d DNS_NAME"
    exit
end


 
# add option switch and handler
 
options = {}
 
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
   
# DNS_NAME argument
 options[:dns_name] = nil
    opts.on('-d', '--dns-name DNS_NAME', 'Specify a DNS NAME') { |dns_name| options[:dns_name] = dns_name }
   
# HELP argument
    options[:help] = nil
    opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Display usage') { |help| options[:help] = help }
end
 
option_parser.parse!
 
# verify arguments
 
if options[:dns_name] then
    dns_name = options[:dns_name]
else
  puts "Please set a balancer's DNS."
  print_usage
  exit
end
 
if options[:help] then
    print_usage
    exit
end
 
# Keep STDOUT
# orig_stdout = $stdout
 
# redirect stdout to /dev/null
# $stdout = File.new('/dev/null', 'w')
 
    server1_visit_count = 0
    server2_visit_count = 0
    server3_visit_count = 0
    server4_visit_count = 0
 
# starting to visit load balancing server
 
puts "Starting to visit load balancing server"

2000.times do

# visit load balancer
# o = "curl #{dns_name}"

o = "curl -s #{dns_name}"
if o =~ /server\s*1/i
    server1_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*2/i
    server2_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*3/i
    server3_visit_count += 1
elsif o =~ /server\s*4/i
    server4_visit_count += 1
end

    print "."
end

puts
puts '-------------------------'
puts ' Summary'
puts '-------------------------'
puts "Server1 visit counts : " + server1_visit_count.to_s
puts "Server2 visit counts : " + server2_visit_count.to_s
puts "Server3 visit counts : " + server3_visit_count.to_s
puts "Server4 visit counts : " + server4_visit_count.to_s
puts "total is: " +  (server1_visit_count + server2_visit_count + server3_visit_count + server4_visit_count).to_s
```

Comment: It doesn't meet this condition `if o =~ /server\s*1/i` as well as other elsif's